# Prolog - XPCE interface running as .exe file

Tags: swi-prolog, xpce

Is it possible to create an interface in XPCE for the program written in PROLOG language. Compile it once and then run as a .exe file, without an SWI prolog console? I am working on MS Windows system.

Comment: Have you considered http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html ?  Which Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using SWI prolog implementation, with SWI Prolog-Editor.

Comment: Yes I know about this C++ interface to SWI Prolog, but I have already done program using only prolog and XPCE package for GUI making. Is there some simple way to transform this prolog file (running with SWI Prolog Compiler) to the same program, but running without the SWI compiler... only .exe?

Comment: I think you should look at the bottom of this section: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compilation